How to transform 'panel data' structure into a data structure suitable for Cox Regression?
I made up some dummy data that has a very similar structure as our internal data I cannot share.
I would like to know how to prepare it for the Cox Regression.
Could you help me to pre-process the dummy data into a structure suitable for the Cox Regression, please? The code that generates the dummy data is below.
Please, take into account that some ‘smokers’ start smoking only a few years before death. This information must be in the data you could pass to the Cox Regression.
My attempt of data pre-processing for the purposes of Cox Regression is COX_DATA2. Do you think that it is possible approach?
    data Cox_data;
    personID=1;     *smoker who died at the age of 9;
    do age=1 to 9;
        if age<=8 then dead=0; else dead=1;
        if age<=6 then no_cigars=0; else no_cigars=age/2; * # of cigarettes smoked per day;
        if dead=1 then no_cigars=0;
        output;
    end;
    personID=2;     *smoker who died at the age of 6;
    do age=1 to 6;
        if age<=5 then dead=0; else dead=1;
        if age<=3 then no_cigars=0; else no_cigars=age/2.2;
        if dead=1 then no_cigars=0;
        output;
    end;
    personID=3;     *smoker who died at the age of 13;
    do age=1 to 13;
        if age<=12 then dead=0; else dead=1;
        if age<=7 then no_cigars=0; else no_cigars=age/3;
        if dead=1 then no_cigars=0;
        output;
    end;
    personID=4;     *non-smoker died at the age of 17;
    do age=1 to 17;
        if age<=16 then dead=0; else dead=1;
        if age<=20 then no_cigars=0; else no_cigars=age/2;
        if dead=1 then no_cigars=0;
        output;
    end;
    personID=5;     *smoker who did not die during the measured time;
    do age=1 to 13;
        if age<=15 then dead=0; else dead=1;
        if age<=6 then no_cigars=0; else no_cigars=1;
        if dead=1 then no_cigars=0;
        output;
    end;
    personID=6;     *non-smoker who did not die during the measured time;
    do age=1 to 11;
        if age<=15 then dead=0; else dead=1;
        if age<=15 then no_cigars=0; else no_cigars=1;
        if dead=1 then no_cigars=0;
        output;
    end;
    run;

    * can Cox_data2 be used for Cox regression?;
    data cox_data2;
    set cox_data;

    if personID=1 then time2Death=9-age;
    if personID=2 then time2Death=6-age;
    if personID=3 then time2Death=13-age;
    if personID=4 then time2Death=17-age;
    if personID=5 then time2Death=14-age;
    if personID=6 then time2Death=12-age;

    if personID<=4 then willDie=1; else willDie=0;
    if dead then delete;
    drop dead;
    run;

My belief is that the following Proc PHREG could be used, although all the people in the dummy data have multiple records.
    *My application on Cox Regression;
    proc phreg data=Cox_data2 COVS(AGGREGATE);
        model time2Death*willDie(0) = age no_cigars;
        ID personId;
        baseline out=out2 survival=surv cumhaz=CH;
    run;

Is my approach to create COX_DATA2 and run Cox Regression on it correct?
Here is how COX_DATA2 looks for the first 2 people:

Here is the result from my run of Proc PHReg:


It would be helpful to show your model and desired data.  I am just guessing here.
data tte;
   set cox_data;
   by personID dead notsorted;
   if first.dead and dead eq 'Y' then do;
      tte=age;
      censor=0;
      output;
      end;
   if last.PersonID and dead eq 'N' then do;
      tte=age;
      censor=1;
      output;
      end;
   drop no_cigars;
   run;
   
proc summary data=cox_data nway;
   class personID;
   output out=no_cigars(drop=_:) mean(no_Cigars)=;
   run;

data tte;
   merge tte no_cigars;
   by personid;
   run;

proc phreg data=tte;
   model tte*censor(1) = no_cigars;
   run;




Please, I edited my question based on your reply. Is it OK if you review my own solution?
